# Exception while receiving OTA update: TCP connection is not from a google app, closing it

Tags: ota-update, samsung-galaxy-gear, android-wear

I'm trying to update over the air the firmware of my Samsung Gear Live. Current build number is KKV81.

But when I go to System updates I see the message: 
"Something went wrong. Try again?"

In the same time in logcat (through usb dongle) I see this:

```
08-07 20:06:40.620      606-606/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ onCreate
08-07 20:06:41.660      454-569/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS cmp=com.google.android.gms/.update.SystemUpdateWearableActivity} from pid 619 on display 0
08-07 20:06:41.720      606-606/? D/SystemUpdateActivity﹕ status=6 mobile=false batteryState=0 roaming=false lastCheckinTime=1407349343493 mSetupWizard=false
08-07 20:06:41.780      454-474/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.google.android.gms/.update.SystemUpdateWearableActivity: +105ms
08-07 20:06:42.000      662-682/? W/bt-btif﹕ dm_pm_timer expires
08-07 20:06:42.000      662-682/? W/bt-btif﹕ dm_pm_timer expires 0
08-07 20:06:42.000      662-682/? W/bt-btif﹕ proc dm_pm_timer expires
08-07 20:06:43.620      606-606/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ onCreate
08-07 20:06:43.650     606-1692/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ network: NetworkInfo: type: PROXY[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: enabled, extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false; metered: false; mobile allowed: true
08-07 20:06:43.650     606-1692/? I/DownloadAttempt﹕ current file is null
08-07 20:06:43.650     606-1692/? I/DownloadAttempt﹕ mSize -1 mDownloaded -1
08-07 20:06:43.650     606-1692/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ status is 1 (ready)
08-07 20:06:43.650     606-1692/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ starting download of http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/global_samsung_sprat/9463bb9866a01116311155b89e4aae4c436db98c.signed-sprat-KMV78Y-from-KKV81.9463bb98.zip
08-07 20:06:43.660      606-606/? D/SystemUpdateActivity﹕ status=2 mobile=false batteryState=0 roaming=false lastCheckinTime=1407349343493 mSetupWizard=false
08-07 20:06:43.660     606-1692/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ now status is 2 (in_progress)
08-07 20:06:43.670     606-1693/? I/DownloadAttempt﹕ querying downloadmanager
08-07 20:06:43.690     606-1693/? I/DownloadAttempt﹕ mUrl is http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/global_samsung_sprat/9463bb9866a01116311155b89e4aae4c436db98c.signed-sprat-KMV78Y-from-KKV81.9463bb98.zip
08-07 20:06:43.700     606-1693/? I/DownloadAttempt﹕ including auth header <AUTH_HEADER_HERE>...
08-07 20:06:43.710     606-1694/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ network: NetworkInfo: type: PROXY[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: enabled, extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false; metered: false; mobile allowed: true
08-07 20:06:43.710     606-1694/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ now status is 2 (in_progress)
08-07 20:06:44.690      168-169/? E/clockwork_proxy_native﹕ Cannot find uid for tcp connection from 192.168.167.239:44849 to 212.0.195.142:80
08-07 20:06:44.690    1378-1453/? D/ClockworkProxy﹕ TCP connection requested by uid=-1
08-07 20:06:44.690    1378-1453/? D/ClockworkProxy﹕ TCP connection is not from a google app, closing it...
08-07 20:06:44.700     606-1693/? I/DownloadAttempt﹕ caught ioexception
    java.io.EOFException
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:342)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:311)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:353)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:297)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:509)
            at apc.b(SourceFile:328)
            at apc.doInBackground(SourceFile:44)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-07 20:06:44.710     606-1697/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ network: NetworkInfo: type: PROXY[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: enabled, extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false; metered: false; mobile allowed: true
08-07 20:06:44.710     606-1697/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ now status is 5 (failed)
08-07 20:06:44.730      606-606/? D/SystemUpdateActivity﹕ status=6 mobile=false batteryState=0 roaming=false lastCheckinTime=1407349343493 mSetupWizard=false
08-07 20:06:44.730     606-1697/? I/SystemUpdateService﹕ download failed; clearing attempt
08-07 20:06:44.750      606-610/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 298K, 9% free 6140K/6724K, paused 3ms+11ms, total 41ms
08-07 20:06:44.760     606-1697/? V/SystemUpdateService﹕ retry (wakeup: true) in 19969 ms
08-07 20:06:49.230      454-483/? I/PowerManagerService﹕ Going to sleep by user request...
```

What can be done here to proceed with OTA update? Where can I fire this bug to Google?

P.s.: corresponding [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/gear-live/help/firmware-update-wrong-t2827814#post54677277) on he xda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to update the watch. This error persisted while I was staying in 3g-zone of local operator - Unite (Moldova). (I tried both - sharing 3g connection from the Android phone and sharing 3g connection from router, in both cases update was failed with stacktrace above). As soon as I moved home to the fixed ethernet network I was able to proceed with update. In the same time, it was quite hard to proceed with installing update after it was actually downloaded. The "yes" button in the prompt "Do I want to install update" was clickable, but there happened nothing on click. Finally, after restarting and unknown action from me I was able to make update. I am happy now. :)

So, try to move to other internet provider and try to update there.